# Force go to read multiple bytes for a Uvarint

Tags: binary, go

Lets say I have the following 2 byte array, that I've read from a file.

```
bits := []byte{3, 223}
```

I would like to interpret this as one integer, which would be 991 (`0b11` from the first number, `0b11011111` from the second). I'm trying to do this with Go and running into difficulty.

```
import "encoding/binary"
import "fmt"

bits := []byte{3, 223}
fmt.Println(binary.Uvarint(bits))
```

This reads the "3" and then stops. Similarly for binary.Read... etc.

I'm sure there is some idiom that I am missing here, and would appreciate your help.

Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I needed to use the [ByteOrder](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder) constructor

```
import "encoding/binary"
import "fmt"

bits := []byte{3, 223}
fmt.Println(binary.BigEndian.Uint16(bits))
```

Comment: Right, Uvarint is an encoding mechanism: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding?csw=1

You can see why 3 wasn't reading the next byte, 3 is 0000 0011 and the msb needs to be 1. (And if you were reading it correctly it wouldn't have been what you wanted anyway). :)